# node JS more than is incorrect

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi im pretty sure what im about to post might not be enough info (if so please let me know what more is needed).  I am using node js and having a really weird error.  Below is the code and output.

```
if (currentPrice > variableData[i].stopLossHard) {
    console.log('if')
    console.log(currentPrice)
    console.log('is more than')
    console.log(variableData[i].stoplossHard)
}
```

Output:

> if
> 92.7
> is more than
> 93.62700000000001

This is consistently happening.  I also made sure that both `currentPrice` and `variableData[i].stopLossHard` are numbers and not strings (I made sure in the code and in the output its the color of a number not a string)

Any ideas is highly appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the values provided. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3x7dLsve/)

Comment: What version of Node.js? [I cannot reproduce it in v12.16.1](https://repl.it/repls/FrequentOpenMysql)

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. I suggest you learn to use the Developer Console in your browser to set a break point and inspect the values of your variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute you print is different than the one you check  in the if statement:
(In the if stopLossHard has a capital L,  stop-L-ossHard, what you print doesn't)
Try this:

```
if (currentPrice > variableData[i].stoplossHard) {
    console.log('if')
    console.log(currentPrice)
    console.log('is more than')
    console.log(variableData[i].stoplossHard)
}
```

Comment: Good catch - `variableData[i].stopLossHard` is likely undefined, so `currentPrice` would be greater than it.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, ;) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks sooooo much!!!!! This is exactly it, spent so much time on this, combed through thousands of lines of code over and over again, set tons of console logs and break points. then tried to figure out how to break down into smaller example and couldnt figure out how. You are a Life Saver!!!